# Add New Input filed in exiting nop commerce views and create database for that input in DB in nop commerce 4.2

Tags: nopcommerce

I have recently started working on the NOP commerce 4.2 project.

I want to add some input fields in the existing views and save it to the database. I don't have the complete idea about how can I override existing views in my plugin without touching existing views and controllers.
I am looking for step by step approach to override view and save data into the database.

I  have searched a lot but not found any solution which provides the full flow of like this requirement.

Your help will help many people who are facing same issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please tell me which view you want to override? Did you check https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/topic/44064/override-view-in-a-plugin post of the forum.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for Nopcommerce and Nopcommerce plugin development. They have specified everything which I think you need to know before developing any plugin in Nopcommerce.

Comment: what nopCommerce version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use IViewLocationExpander for override view.
1) Create one class, Name like PluginViewLoctionExpander. And inherit it with IViewLocationExpander interface.

```
public class PluginViewLoctionExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
   public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations){
       if (context.AreaName == null && context.ViewName == "ContactUs")
            {
                viewLocations = new[] {"~Yourpath/Common/ContactUs.cshtml",
                }.Concat(viewLocations);
            }
        return viewLocations;
   }
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

2) Create PluginStartUp.cs file.

```
public class PluginStartUp : INopStartup
    {
        public int Order
        {
            get { return 1001; }
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
        {
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new PluginViewLoctionExpander());
            });
        }
    }
```

With this you will display your view and override nop.Web and Admin views.
I hope this is help for you.